# Hibernate: openSession vs getCurrentSession

Tags: hibernate, java

В каких случаях какой метод следует использовать?

Я знаю, что getCurrentSession получает/создает сессию, привязанную к контексту, указанному в параметре `hibernate.current_session_context_class`, и знаю то, что она закрывается при окончании транзакции. А вот openSession всегда создает новую сессию, которую нужно вручную закрывать. Если я прав, конечно.

Но я не понимаю, в каких случаях какой способ нужно использовать. Подскажите. Спасибо.

Comment: В гугле полно ответов на этот вопрос. Вы не читали или читали, но не поняли? Если второе, то поясните, что именно непонятно.

Comment: @Dazar по сабжу сказать есть что ?